# If ID exists in other table, show null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've made a conversation system which shows a list of the conversations you've had.
You can delete(hide) a message.

The problem is, when all messages are hidden, it shows an (appearantly?) random message instead. It should not show the name or anything.

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY datotid DESC) as inv
WHERE fk_bruger_til = '$brugerid'
GROUP BY fk_bruger_fra
ORDER BY datotid DESC
```

And the database structure:

Message table:

```
message_id | fk_user_to | fk_user_from | message | datetime | read
```

Hidden messages table:

```
deleted_id | fk_message_id | fk_user_id
```

Comment: what happens if the `post_id` from messages table is not present in `fk_post_id` on hidden messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having two separate tables for messages/hidden messages why not just have an addition field in the messages table that denotes whether it is hidden by a 1 / 0.

This should make your sql query easier to write.

Also may make it easier if you can explain what the table fields mean. Only one i can make out is datetoid.

Comment: I thought it'd be wiser to have it in a seperate table, as user1 can hide a message, while user2 can still see it as user2 didn't hide it. 
I'll translate the tables now :-)